# Use wildcards in ado.net sybase parameter

Tags: c#, parameters, ado.net, wildcard, sqlanywhere

Does some one know, how to use wildcards with ado.net parameter in sybase sql anywhere?

For example i want to search for all names, starting with `Se`. In a normal query i would use `select * from names where name like 'Se%'`. But in ADO.Net my query looks like `SELECT * from names where name like ?` and the question mark will be set over `SAParameter`.

```
SACommand command = new SACommand(SqlStatement, cConnection);
command.Parameters.Add(new SAParameter() { Value = "Se%" });
```

The problem is, `Value` could not contains any wildcards.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my solution example

```
using (SAConnection con = new SAConnection(DBConnStr))
{
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        string sql = "select * from names where name like ?";
        SACommand cmd = new SACommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1","Se%");
        SADataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rdr["name"].ToString());
        }
        rdr.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```